# Блокируется основной поток при запущенном сервисе в android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, service

Здравствуйте.Есть класс `Main_2_Activity` в котором переопределен `onDestroy`, при срабатывании метода onDestroy запускаю сервис класс (`startService(new Intent(Main_2_Activity.this,СервисКласс.class))`).В сервис классе есть `AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>` внутри которого бесконечный цикл а в цикле есть`TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10)`..Кроме этих классов есть еще один активити `MainActivity` который показывает превью(картинку) приложения при запуске приложения и через 3 секунды автоматом переходит на `Main_2_Activity`.Переход в `Main_2_Activity` происходит тоже в отдельном потоке `(AsyncTask)`.И если приложение закрыть (запуск Service) и открыть то переход из `MainActivity` к  `Main_2_Activity` не происходит.Приложение зависает показывая превью.Но если убираю startService из onDestroy то все нормально работает.

В чем может быть проблема?

#### Код:

#### MainActivity.class

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new MyAsync2().execute();
}

class MyAsync2 extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            for(int i =0;i<3;i++){
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main_2_Activity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

#### Main_2_Activity.class

```
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();

        //тут еще немного кода

        startService(new Intent(Main_2_Activity.this,Timer_Alert.class));
        Toast.makeText(this,"Сервис запущен!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

#### Сервис класс

```
public class Timer_Alert extends Service {


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        new MyAsync().execute();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                this.getClass());
        restartService.setPackage(getPackageName());
        PendingIntent restartServicePI = PendingIntent.getService(
                getApplicationContext(), 1, restartService,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +1000, restartServicePI);

    }


public class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            try {
                BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("path.txt"),"UTF-8"));
                path = bf.readLine();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            if(json==null){
                try {
                    InputStream is = getAssets().open(path+".json");
                    int size = is.available();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                    is.read(buffer);
                    is.close();
                    json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
                    Log.e("input_onPreExecute : ",json.length()+"");
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }

            }try {
                year = new JSONObject(json);
                months = year.getJSONObject("month"+mmon);
                dayJs = months.getJSONObject("day_"+dday);
                Log.e("JSON_onPreExecute : ",""+dayJs.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            }
            hrs = hh+":"+min;
            try {
                strJson = dayJs.getString("блаблабла");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            }
            //тут еще пара if-ов как сверху.

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            String nName=null; 

            try {
                boolean bool = true;
                while(bool){
                    date = new Date();
                    try {
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                    //Тут немного кода...
                    strJson = dayJs.getString("блаблабла");
                     if(hrs.equals(strJson)){
                         nName = "блаблабла";
                         publishProgress();
                         TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1);
                     }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
          //Тут код для показа Notification. 

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),strJson,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Comment: На момент повторного открытия сервис же продолжает работать?

Comment: @PirateNinja да

Comment: Как можно реализовать будильник, чтобы он не блокировал основной поток?(GUI).Есть расписание на целый день.

Comment: Т.е.сервис должен работать целей день.но ему можно пару часов между расписаниями спать.Интервал между каждым событием несколько часов.то есть если он сигналит где то в 12:00 то след должен быть где то 14:00.

Comment: На сколько я помню метод OnDestroy не гарантированный , он может не сработать. Вроде как последний всегда срабатывающий метод onPause. Это кажется где то и офф.документации есть. К проблеме это отношения не имеет. Так, к вашему сведению

Comment: Незнаю почему но когда я перевёл все в обычный Thread проблема исчезла